# Can a function and its gradient both be globally Lipschitz?

Tags: lipschitz-functions

I'm interested in non-trivial examples of 
a continuously differentiable function
$f: \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$
such that both $f$ and its gradient $\nabla f$ are both globally Lipschitz.

I could come up with trivial examples where $f$ is constant or affine.
A more interesting example is where $f$ is affine only outside of a bounded set and finite inside
(e.g., the 1d function $f(x) = x^2$ for $|x| \le 1$ 
and $2 |x| - 1$ otherwise),
but I still think that this example is pathological.

Comment: What do you mean by non-trivial?

Answer (score 1):

In 1D: any function $f$ such that $f$, $f'$, $f''$ are bounded will satisfy the requirements thanks to the MVT. Such natural examples are $\arctan, \sin, \cos\ldots$

In nD, in the same spirit: $\exp(-\sum x_i^2)$ for instance.